# How do I get from the top of the skyscraper to the water without touching the ground?

Tags: here-comes-niko

In Hairball City, after getting the Contract List from Tadpole HQ, the Game Kid has a mission to jump from the top of the skyscraper into the water without touching the ground.

How do I get to the water without touching the ground?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the top of the skyscraper, go to the indicated corner (1), then you can easily jump onto the blue umbrella (2), then dive into the water (3).

[image]